# BaseAdapter's Custom dialog recycler view not updating andorid

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridview, dialog, baseadapter

I do have a grid view implemented with base adapter. In each view there is a click listener. When we click on that, a Custom Dialog will open. In that dialog there is a Recycler view. That is updating each 10 seconds with the help of timer. That's updating perfectly. ***But when the custom dialog is opened and wait for next 10 sec to update the recycler view will not update the recycler view. But when i dismiss that dialog and immediately reopened then it will show updated recycler view.***

*RV is not updating when Custom dialog poped up*

I want to update recycler view while the custom dialog poped up.

Git: https://github.com/jishnunkrishnan/baseadaptersample

Here is the code:

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.aijishnu.baseadaptersample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.aijishnu.baseadaptersample.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityMainBinding binding;
    int i = 0;
    Context c;
    ArrayList<String> alNames;
    int[] arrayImages;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        c = this;
        arrayImages = new int[] {
                R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground,
                R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground,
                R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground
        };

        alNames = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0;i<5; i++) {
            alNames.add("Raju: " + i);
        }
        updateData();

        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        for (int i=0;i<5; i++) {
                            alNames.add("Raju Radha: " + i);
                        }
                        updateData();
                        Toast.makeText(c, i + " times", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                i++;
            }
        },15000,10000);
    }

    private void updateData() {

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, arrayImages, alNames);
        binding.gvImages.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gvImages"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MyAdaper.java:

```
package com.aijishnu.baseadaptersample;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import com.aijishnu.baseadaptersample.databinding.CustomDesignBinding;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    int[] arrayImages;
    DataAdapter dataAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> alNames;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private boolean isDVisible = false;

    MyAdapter(Context context, int[] arrayImages, ArrayList<String> alNames) {

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayImages = arrayImages;
        this.alNames = alNames;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_layout, null);
        }
        ImageView imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(arrayImages[position]);

        if (isDVisible) {
            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Dialog d = new Dialog(context);
                isDVisible = true;
                CustomDesignBinding binding = CustomDesignBinding.inflate(mInflater);
                d.setContentView(binding.getRoot());
                Window window = d.getWindow();
                assert window != null;
                window.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                binding.rvData.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
                dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(alNames);
                binding.rvData.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                d.show();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

DataAdapter.java

```
package com.aijishnu.baseadaptersample;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.aijishnu.baseadaptersample.databinding.DesignBinding;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.Holder> {

    private ArrayList<String> alNames;
    public DataAdapter(ArrayList<String> names) {

        this.alNames = names;
    }

    static class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final DesignBinding binding;

        public Holder (DesignBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());

            this.binding = binding;
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DataAdapter.Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        return new DataAdapter.Holder(DesignBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DataAdapter.Holder holder, int position) {

        holder.binding.tvName.setText(alNames.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { return alNames.size(); }
}
```

grid_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
</LinearLayout>
```

design.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

custom_desgin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvData"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the adapter of the dialog in the timer callback like this:

**MainActivity.java**

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActivityMainBinding binding;
    int counter = 0;
    Context c;
    ArrayList<String> alNames;
    int[] arrayImages;
    MyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        c = this;

        setupData();
        setupAdapter();

        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    ArrayList<String> newItems = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        newItems.add("Raju Radha: " + ++counter);
                    }
                    updateData(newItems);
                    Toast.makeText(c, counter + " times", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                });
            }
        }, 15000, 10000);
    }

    private void setupAdapter() {
        adapter = new MyAdapter(this, arrayImages, alNames);
        binding.gvImages.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void setupData() {
        arrayImages = new int[]{
                R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground,
                R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground,
                R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground
        };

        alNames = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            alNames.add("Raju: " + i);
        }
    }

    private void updateData(ArrayList<String> newItems) {
        adapter.addItem(newItems);
    }
}
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```java
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    int[] arrayImages;
    DataAdapter dataAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> alNames;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    Dialog d;

    MyAdapter(Context context, int[] arrayImages, ArrayList<String> alNames) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayImages = arrayImages;
        this.alNames = alNames;
        d = new Dialog(context);
        dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(alNames);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_layout, null);
        }
        ImageView imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(arrayImages[position]);

        convertView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            CustomDesignBinding binding = CustomDesignBinding.inflate(mInflater);
            d.setContentView(binding.getRoot());
            Window window = d.getWindow();
            assert window != null;
            window.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            binding.rvData.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context,
                    LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
            binding.rvData.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            d.show();
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public void addItem(ArrayList<String> items) {
        this.dataAdapter.addItems(items);
    }
}
```

**DataAdapter.java**

```java
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.Holder> {
    private final ArrayList<String> alNames;

    public DataAdapter(ArrayList<String> names) {
        this.alNames = names;
    }

    public void addItems(ArrayList<String> items) {
        this.alNames.addAll(items);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    static class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final DesignBinding binding;

        public Holder(DesignBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DataAdapter.Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new DataAdapter.Holder(DesignBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DataAdapter.Holder holder, int position) {
        holder.binding.tvName.setText(alNames.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return alNames.size();
    }
```

Also, I recommend reusing your objects when possible.

Comment: Thank You So much...@Farbod. This works perfectly fine. This was a sample program. But I'm working on a big project exactly to this and facing the same issue. I want this solution to that project. But Everything was right, the issue is not resolved on that project. It was a web based project using volley. Have any suggestion???